# How to access the redux store from a library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I am creating a library for my react application which will handle every API calls related to the session (authenticate, register, refresh token etc...) and this library will need to access the redux store on its own to dispatch actions.
The reason behind this is whenever the access token of the user expires, using a setTimeout I need to call an action creator that will call my API to refresh the token, and update the application redux store with the new session data.

So I was thinking to pass the dispatch method to the library whenever I call it for the first time, but I'm not sure that's the best way to do it.

Or I could also create an `initialize()` method that will pass the dispatch to the library.

```
import { authenticate } from 'libraries/session';

export function login(email, password) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(loginRequest());

        return authenticate(email, password, dispatch) // dispatch is passed here, so I can use it later in the library
        .then(() => (
            dispatch(loginSuccess())
        ))
        .catch((json) => (
            dispatch(loginError());
        ));
    };
};
```

I haven't tried this code yet, it's more of a brainstorming for now.

Would you have any suggestion of the best way to handle this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered doing this as a middleware?

Comment: I thought about this, but I have no idea how I could do it with middleware, an example would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My impulse would be swap the params:

```
import { authenticate } from 'libraries/session';


export function configureLogin(store) {
    var {dispatch, subscribe, getState} = store;
    return (email, password) => {
        dispatch(loginRequest());

        return authenticate(email, password, dispatch) // <- I don't why dispatch needs to be included, but I'll take ur word for it
        .then(() => dispatch(loginSuccess())
        .catch(json => dispatch(loginError()));
    };
};

// usage
import { configureLogin } from './service/login';
var store = createStore();
var login = configureLogin(store);
login(email, password);
```

Comment: I've finally done something similar to that thanks! :)